# Conversion of string to double without scientific notation in C++

Tags: c++, string, double, precision, scientific-notation

I have a string variable and want to convert it into double without any scientific notation. I tried using `std::stod` but that doesn't work.

```
std::stringstream timestamp;
timestamp << t_val;
string test = timestamp.str();
cout << test << endl; // this gives 1506836639.96
double d = std::stod(test);
cout << d << endl; // This gives 1.50684e+09 instead of 1506836639.96
```

I tried using `setprecision` and `fixed` but I couldn't store the result into a variable. Is there a way I can store the value of `test` (1506836639.96) as a double?

Comment: The scientific notation is in the printout, not in the `double` value.

Comment: Use this value for computations, but when you finally want to print it, convert it back to string via `std::to_string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scientific notation has to do with `std::cout`, not the way the value is stored, so you must use `std::fixed` before you print the value:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << d << std::endl;
```

As you can see in the demo, this works fine, it should work for you as well.

As [@goodvibration commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335017/conversion-of-string-to-double-without-scientific-notation-in-c/62335098#comment110245419_62335017) `std::to_string` also works but it's not possible to redefine, in a simple manner, the default number or decimal places in this case.

```
std::cout << std::to_string(d) << std::endl;
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ogvyEo878kktUxyh)